# AdMob Banners and GLSurfaceview

Tags: android, opengl-es, admob, glsurfaceview, banner-ads

I can't solve the problem of the second day. AdMob banner is not displayed. Working in Android Studio. Copied [Android Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start) (all updates downloaded). Help please.

**onCreate()** method:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


            setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
            glView = (GLSurfaceView) this.findViewById (R.id.glSurface);
    //
            //glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
            glView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0); // crutch
            glView.setRenderer(this);
    //      //setContentView(glView);

            glGraphics = new GLGraphics(glView);
            fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(getAssets());
            audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
            input = new AndroidInput(this, glView, 1, 1);
            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "GLGame");


            AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .addTestDevice("0CE08511E868CB06C13E5CB25A4F1C82").build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thecolors"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name=".TheColorsGame"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        !--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>


    <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/glSurface"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </FrameLayout>
```

**LogCat**

```
03-13 22:22:28.350  12680-12723/com.thecolors I/AndroidRuntime﹕ VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
03-13 22:23:25.530  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-13 22:23:25.690  17333-17357/com.thecolors V/SoundPoolThread﹕ beginThread
03-13 22:23:25.690  17333-17357/com.thecolors V/SoundPoolThread﹕ run
03-13 22:23:25.715  17333-17333/com.thecolors E/SensorManager﹕ thread start
03-13 22:23:25.725  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 20000 Listener= com.framework.impl.AccelerometerHandler@42cc53e0
03-13 22:23:25.790  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 148K, 9% free 12426K/13511K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
03-13 22:23:25.830  17333-17334/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 20K, 8% free 12460K/13511K, paused 13ms+13ms, total 40ms
03-13 22:23:25.900  17333-17334/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 151K, 8% free 12844K/13959K, paused 11ms+6ms, total 31ms
03-13 22:23:25.945  17333-17333/com.thecolors I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.g.a
03-13 22:23:25.945  17333-17333/com.thecolors W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 3097: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.getDefaultUserAgent (Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/lang/String;
03-13 22:23:25.945  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0011
03-13 22:23:26.030  17333-17334/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 214K, 9% free 13107K/14279K, paused 14ms+12ms, total 46ms
03-13 22:23:26.050  17333-17333/com.thecolors I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.ew.c
03-13 22:23:26.050  17333-17333/com.thecolors W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 441: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
03-13 22:23:26.050  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000f
03-13 22:23:26.060  17333-17376/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads2130424813.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
03-13 22:23:26.210  17333-17333/com.thecolors I/webclipboard﹕ clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@42d9a4d8
03-13 22:23:26.235  17333-17376/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- END 'ads2130424813.jar' (success) ---
03-13 22:23:26.235  17333-17376/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ DEX prep '/data/data/com.thecolors/cache/ads2130424813.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 176ms
03-13 22:23:26.435  17333-17333/com.thecolors I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
03-13 22:23:26.435  17333-17393/com.thecolors V/webkit﹕ BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {42d7e080}
03-13 22:23:26.475  17333-17334/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 369K, 10% free 13205K/14535K, paused 2ms+12ms, total 48ms
03-13 22:23:26.585  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
03-13 22:23:26.595  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
03-13 22:23:26.595  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
03-13 22:23:26.600  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/﹕ Device driver API match
    Device driver API version: 10
    User space API version: 10
03-13 22:23:26.600  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012
03-13 22:23:26.655  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-13 22:23:26.780  17333-17355/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 53K, 9% free 13257K/14535K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
03-13 22:23:26.805  17333-17355/com.thecolors I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 21.861MB for 8388624-byte allocation
03-13 22:23:26.840  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 21448K/22791K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
03-13 22:23:26.880  17333-17334/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 21453K/22791K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 38ms
03-13 22:23:29.080  17333-17404/com.thecolors I/Ads﹕ No fill from ad server.
03-13 22:23:29.085  17333-17333/com.thecolors I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMixedContentMode, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.p.a.<init>
03-13 22:23:29.085  17333-17333/com.thecolors W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3111: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.setMixedContentMode (I)V
03-13 22:23:29.085  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x003f
03-13 22:23:29.085  17333-17333/com.thecolors I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.p.a.<init>
03-13 22:23:29.085  17333-17333/com.thecolors W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3110: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture (Z)V
03-13 22:23:29.085  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0054
03-13 22:23:29.085  17333-17333/com.thecolors I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.p.a.evaluateJavascript
03-13 22:23:29.085  17333-17333/com.thecolors W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3121: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.evaluateJavascript (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/webkit/ValueCallback;)V
03-13 22:23:29.085  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0016
03-13 22:23:29.090  17333-17333/com.thecolors I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.p.a.isAttachedToWindow, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.p.a.onDraw
03-13 22:23:29.090  17333-17333/com.thecolors W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4882: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/internal/p/a;.isAttachedToWindow ()Z
03-13 22:23:29.090  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000c
03-13 22:23:29.090  17333-17333/com.thecolors I/webclipboard﹕ clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@42d9a4d8
03-13 22:23:29.095  17333-17393/com.thecolors V/webkit﹕ BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {42d5c828}
03-13 22:23:29.140  17333-17355/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8380K, 42% free 13316K/22791K, paused 23ms, total 24ms
03-13 22:23:29.145  17333-17355/com.thecolors I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 21.844MB for 8310980-byte allocation
03-13 22:23:29.160  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 21432K/22791K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
03-13 22:23:29.175  17333-17333/com.thecolors W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 3
03-13 22:23:29.190  17333-17334/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 8K, 6% free 21435K/22791K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 32ms
03-13 22:23:29.200  17333-17333/com.thecolors D/webviewglue﹕ nativeDestroy view: 0x5b071b50
03-13 22:26:57.165  17333-17334/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 10103K, 46% free 13287K/24391K, paused 14ms+3ms, total 48ms
03-13 22:27:38.000  17333-17334/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 385K, 46% free 13286K/24391K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 40ms
03-13 22:28:18.885  17333-17334/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 46% free 13286K/24391K, paused 13ms+3ms, total 37ms
03-13 22:28:59.760  17333-17334/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 46% free 13286K/24391K, paused 12ms+4ms, total 38ms
03-13 22:29:40.710  17333-17334/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 46% free 13286K/24391K, paused 6ms+3ms, total 30ms
03-13 22:30:21.675  17333-17334/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 46% free 13286K/24391K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 37ms
03-13 22:31:02.635  17333-17334/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 46% free 13286K/24391K, paused 12ms+4ms, total 37ms
03-13 22:31:43.590  17333-17334/com.thecolors D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 46% free 13286K/24391K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 37ms
```

Comment: `glView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);` - can u try commenting it ?  is your `GLSurfaceView` transparent ?

Comment: >glView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0); - I don't know what is this if be honest. It is some duct tape which I found in net. Without this don't work anything.

Comment: try changing your package name and see, do you get this error when you test on api 17+ ? it has to do with the method on the websettings it is using methods added in 17+ etc, the problem is why is it using it, if you are testing on real device clear your playservice data or rename your package name and see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you got to solve this, but I struggled for a couple of nights with this same issue. This is how I solved it.

I have an app which also has a GLSurfaceview. What I did to be able to show the banner ads, is to include the AdView in the layout, at the top (I have a LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#00000000">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/scene1Holder"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxx">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Then, in the onCreate, before adding the glSurfaceView to the layout, I initialize the adview:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.scene1Holder);

AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
.
.
.
ll.addView(_glSurfaceView);
```

In my app, I was also able to display Intersitial ads, just make sure to use a different AdRequest object.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for a possible solution.